# Show that L and Images cannot both be finite

Tags: automata

im trying to complete these exercises for my automata theory class. The book i have explains this stuff really badly. Im kinda lost on how to start this as im not sure what I should be looking at.

Let L be any language on a non-empty alphabet. Show that L and The Complement of L cannot both be finite.

i know the complement of L ( ill use L# for the compliment of L) L#= E^*-L  but i dont know were to go from their.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let `a` be a letter of your alphabet. Assume for sake of contradiction both `L` and its complement `L#` are finite. Then, their union, `L+L#`, is finite. But `L+L#` contains all words `a^n` for natural `n`, i.e. infinitely many, a contradiction.

This is as much about infinite sets as it is about automata and languages: you cannot split an infinite set into a finite number of finite sets.

Comment: ahh so basically , because its an infinite set , u cant break it up and make finite sets from them. so the infinite set is always infinite. i saw a proof that showed that infinite - infinite = finite . is this true? it just seems wrong lol. it showed. U (union) = infinite , and L = infinite. therefore L#=U-L = infinite-infinite which is finite.